# Recursively group nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, recursion

Below is the data I'm receiving from the server

```
let tableData = {
  data: [
    {
      data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" },
      children: []
    },
    {
      data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" },
      children: []
    },
    {
      data: { name: "two", size: "201", type: "folder" },
      children: []
    },
    {
      data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" },
      children: []
    },
    {
      data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" },
      children: []
    },
    {
      data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "file" },
      children: []
    }
  ]
};
```

I have to group objects by the column names stored here. This can be have multiple column names.

```
let groupedCols = ["name"];
```

In the JSFiddlle example I have managed to create one level of grouping. But it breaks when I change the groupedCols to

```
let groupedCols = ["name", "type"]; or let groupedCols = ["name", "type", "size"];
```

In JSFiddle example, I'm looping through groupedCols array. In the first iteration I'm passing tableDataArr into groupChildren function. But during second iteration I want to pass it's tableDataArr's children into it and so on.

Here's the expected object I want to create

```
tableData = {
  data: [
    {
      data: { name: "one", size: "", type: "" }, // level 1 - grouped by name
      children: [
        {
          data: { name: "", size: "", type: "folder" }, // level 2 - grouped by type
          children: [
            {
              data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" },
            },
            {
              data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" },
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          data: { name: "", size: "", type: "file" }, // level 2 - grouped by type
          children: [
            {
              data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "file" }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      data: { name: "two", size: "", type: "" }, // level 1 - grouped by name
      children: [
        {
          data: { name: "", size: "", type: "folder" }, // level 2 - grouped by type
          children: [
            {
              data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" }
            },
            {
              data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" }
            },
            {
              data: { name: "two", size: "201", type: "folder" }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
};
```

Here's JSFiddle link -
https://jsfiddle.net/jrt1wo6a/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an iterative approach for building the nested groups.

```js
const
    groupBy = (array, groups) => array.reduce((r, { data }) => {
        groups
            .reduce((t, k) => {
                let temp = t.find(q => data[k] === q.data[k]);
                if (!temp) t.push(temp = { data: { name: '', size: '', type: '', [k]: data[k] }, children: [] });
                return temp.children;
            }, r)
            .push({ data });
        return r;
    }, []),
    data = [{ data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" }, children: [] }, { data: { name: "two", size: "200", type: "folder" }, children: [] }, { data: { name: "two", size: "201", type: "folder" }, children: [] }, { data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" }, children: [] }, { data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "folder" }, children: [] }, { data: { name: "one", size: "200", type: "file" }, children: [] }];

console.log(groupBy(data, ["name"]));
console.log(groupBy(data, ["name", "type"]));
console.log(groupBy(data, ["name", "type", "size"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey, In your solution in all scenarios it returns Array of 6 objects. When you group by groupBy(data, ["name"]) it should return only Array of 2 objects. since "one" and "two" are the only unique values in the name column. Please refer to my JSFiddle example where I grouped just by name column.

Comment: When you use groupBy(data, ["name", "type"]). The first level should be grouped by "name" then its children (level 2) should be grouped by "type" within it (Refer my original post expected result for this).

Comment: @xbruteforcex, sorry a data was missing.